# mx.controls.Menu doesn't render properly when built by flexmojos-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, apache-flex, flex3, flexmojos, flex-mojos

I've got wired problem with my Flex application, exactly menu (based on mx.controls.Menu and flexlib.controls.ScrollableMenu).

When I build my application by FlashBuilder menu works. See screenshot:

[image: Menu OK]

But when I build it by maven using flexmojos-sonatype-plugin the menu is broken (it's not rendered properly according to labelField property and it doesn't catch any events like mouse click). See screenshot:

[image: Broken menu]

My .actionScriptProperties file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<actionScriptProperties analytics="false" mainApplicationPath="ats.mxml" projectUUID="802474ea-5e3c-4d2c-bdaa-8c263c0828f4" version="6">
  <compiler additionalCompilerArguments="-locale en_US" autoRSLOrdering="false" copyDependentFiles="true" flexSDK="Flex 3.3" fteInMXComponents="false" generateAccessible="true" htmlExpressInstall="true" htmlGenerate="true" htmlHistoryManagement="true" htmlPlayerVersionCheck="true" includeNetmonSwc="false" outputFolderLocation="D:/flex" outputFolderPath="bin-debug" rootURL="http://localhost:8080/flex/" sourceFolderPath="src/main/flex" strict="true" targetPlayerVersion="0.0.0" useApolloConfig="false" useDebugRSLSwfs="true" verifyDigests="true" warn="true">
    <compilerSourcePath />
    <libraryPath defaultLinkType="1">
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="d:/apps/.m2/repo/com/adobe/flex/framework/automation/3.3.0.4852/automation-3.3.0.4852.swc" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="d:/apps/.m2/repo/com/adobe/flex/framework/automation_agent/3.3.0.4852/automation_agent-3.3.0.4852.swc" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="d:/apps/.m2/repo/com/adobe/flex/framework/automation_dmv/3.3.0.4852/automation_dmv-3.3.0.4852.swc" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="d:/apps/.m2/repo/com/adobe/flex/framework/automation_flashflexkit/3.3.0.4852/automation_flashflexkit-3.3.0.4852.swc" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="d:/apps/.m2/repo/com/adobe/flex/framework/automation_agent/3.3.0.4852/automation_agent-3.3.0.4852-en_US.rb.swc" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="d:/apps/.m2/repo/com/adobe/flex/framework/automation/3.3.0.4852/automation-3.3.0.4852-en_US.rb.swc" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="d:/apps/.m2/repo/com/adobe/flexunit/flexunit/0.90/flexunit-0.90.swc" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="d:/apps/.m2/repo/com/adobe/flex/framework/as3corelib/0.92.1/as3corelib-0.92.1.swc" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="d:/apps/.m2/repo/com/google/code/flexlib/flexlib/2.6-M3/flexlib-2.6-M3.swc" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
      <libraryPathEntry kind="4" path="">
        <modifiedEntries>
          <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/framework.swc" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
        </modifiedEntries>
        <excludedEntries>
          <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/qtp.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
          <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
          <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation_dmv.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
          <libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation_agent.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
        </excludedEntries>
      </libraryPathEntry>
    </libraryPath>
    <sourceAttachmentPath>
      <sourceAttachmentPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/flex.swc" sourcepath="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/source" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
    </sourceAttachmentPath>
  </compiler>
  <applications>
    <application path="myApp.mxml"/>
  </applications>
  <modules/>
  <buildCSSFiles/>
</actionScriptProperties>
```

My effective POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.application.myApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
  <version>trunk-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>swf</packaging>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.flexlib</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexlib</artifactId>
        <version>2.6-M3</version>
        <type>swc</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.flexlib</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexlib</artifactId>
        <type>swc</type>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0.4852</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>playerglobal</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>playerglobal</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0.4852</version>
      <type>swc</type>
      <classifier>10</classifier>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adobe.flexunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>flexunit</artifactId>
      <version>0.90</version>
      <type>swc</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>as3corelib</artifactId>
      <version>0.92.1</version>
      <type>swc</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>datavisualization</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0.4852</version>
      <type>swc</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-http-lightweight</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
          <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.0-RC2</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>sources</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <actionscriptFileEncoding>UTF-8</actionscriptFileEncoding>
                <licenses>
                  <flexbuilder3>...</flexbuilder3>
                </licenses>
                <targetPlayer>10.2.0</targetPlayer>
                <accessible>true</accessible>
                <headlessServer>true</headlessServer>
                <localesCompiled>
                  <locale>en_US</locale>
                </localesCompiled>
                <verboseStacktraces>true</verboseStacktraces>
                <compilerWarnings>
                  <assignmentWithinConditional>true</assignmentWithinConditional>
                  <constructorReturnsValue>true</constructorReturnsValue>
                  <duplicateArgumentNames>true</duplicateArgumentNames>
                  <duplicateVariableDef>true</duplicateVariableDef>
                  <noConstructor>true</noConstructor>
                </compilerWarnings>
                <generateHtmlWrapper>false</generateHtmlWrapper>
                <enableM2e>false</enableM2e>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>swf-optimization</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>optimize-swf</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <attachOriginalArtifact>false</attachOriginalArtifact>
                <reduce>false</reduce>
                <reduceMergeABC>false</reduceMergeABC>
                <reduceMergeCF>false</reduceMergeCF>
                <reduceSortCPool>false</reduceSortCPool>
                <strip>false</strip>
                <actionscriptFileEncoding>UTF-8</actionscriptFileEncoding>
                <licenses>
                  <flexbuilder3>...</flexbuilder3>
                </licenses>
                <targetPlayer>10.2.0</targetPlayer>
                <accessible>true</accessible>
                <headlessServer>true</headlessServer>
                <localesCompiled>
                  <locale>en_US</locale>
                </localesCompiled>
                <verboseStacktraces>true</verboseStacktraces>
                <compilerWarnings>
                  <assignmentWithinConditional>true</assignmentWithinConditional>
                  <constructorReturnsValue>true</constructorReturnsValue>
                  <duplicateArgumentNames>true</duplicateArgumentNames>
                  <duplicateVariableDef>true</duplicateVariableDef>
                  <noConstructor>true</noConstructor>
                </compilerWarnings>
                <generateHtmlWrapper>false</generateHtmlWrapper>
                <enableM2e>false</enableM2e>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
              <artifactId>license</artifactId>
              <version>3</version>
              <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
              <artifactId>flexmojos-flex3-compatibility-layer</artifactId>
              <version>4.0-RC2</version>
              <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
              <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
              <version>3.3.0.4852</version>
              <type>pom</type>
              <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
              <artifactId>adt</artifactId>
              <version>3.3.0.4852</version>
              <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
            <actionscriptFileEncoding>UTF-8</actionscriptFileEncoding>
            <licenses>
              <flexbuilder3>...</flexbuilder3>
            </licenses>
            <targetPlayer>10.2.0</targetPlayer>
            <accessible>true</accessible>
            <headlessServer>true</headlessServer>
            <localesCompiled>
              <locale>en_US</locale>
            </localesCompiled>
            <verboseStacktraces>true</verboseStacktraces>
            <compilerWarnings>
              <assignmentWithinConditional>true</assignmentWithinConditional>
              <constructorReturnsValue>true</constructorReturnsValue>
              <duplicateArgumentNames>true</duplicateArgumentNames>
              <duplicateVariableDef>true</duplicateVariableDef>
              <noConstructor>true</noConstructor>
            </compilerWarnings>
            <generateHtmlWrapper>false</generateHtmlWrapper>
            <enableM2e>false</enableM2e>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <allowTimestampedSnapshots>true</allowTimestampedSnapshots>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-RC2</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile-swf</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile-swf</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceFile>myApp.mxml</sourceFile>
              <ignoreVersionIssues>true</ignoreVersionIssues>
              <skipTests>true</skipTests>
              <compilerWarnings>
                <warn-no-constructor>false</warn-no-constructor>
                <show-binding-warnings>false</show-binding-warnings>
                <warn-duplicate-variable-def>false</warn-duplicate-variable-def>
                <assignmentWithinConditional>true</assignmentWithinConditional>
                <constructorReturnsValue>true</constructorReturnsValue>
                <duplicateArgumentNames>true</duplicateArgumentNames>
                <duplicateVariableDef>true</duplicateVariableDef>
                <noConstructor>true</noConstructor>
              </compilerWarnings>
              <actionscriptFileEncoding>UTF-8</actionscriptFileEncoding>
              <licenses>
                <flexbuilder3>...</flexbuilder3>
              </licenses>
              <targetPlayer>10.2.0</targetPlayer>
              <accessible>true</accessible>
              <headlessServer>true</headlessServer>
              <localesCompiled>
                <locale>en_US</locale>
              </localesCompiled>
              <verboseStacktraces>true</verboseStacktraces>
              <generateHtmlWrapper>false</generateHtmlWrapper>
              <enableM2e>false</enableM2e>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>sources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceFile>myApp.mxml</sourceFile>
              <ignoreVersionIssues>true</ignoreVersionIssues>
              <skipTests>true</skipTests>
              <compilerWarnings>
                <warn-no-constructor>false</warn-no-constructor>
                <show-binding-warnings>false</show-binding-warnings>
                <warn-duplicate-variable-def>false</warn-duplicate-variable-def>
                <assignmentWithinConditional>true</assignmentWithinConditional>
                <constructorReturnsValue>true</constructorReturnsValue>
                <duplicateArgumentNames>true</duplicateArgumentNames>
                <duplicateVariableDef>true</duplicateVariableDef>
                <noConstructor>true</noConstructor>
              </compilerWarnings>
              <actionscriptFileEncoding>UTF-8</actionscriptFileEncoding>
              <licenses>
                <flexbuilder3>...</flexbuilder3>
              </licenses>
              <targetPlayer>10.2.0</targetPlayer>
              <accessible>true</accessible>
              <headlessServer>true</headlessServer>
              <localesCompiled>
                <locale>en_US</locale>
              </localesCompiled>
              <verboseStacktraces>true</verboseStacktraces>
              <generateHtmlWrapper>false</generateHtmlWrapper>
              <enableM2e>false</enableM2e>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>swf-optimization</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>optimize-swf</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <attachOriginalArtifact>false</attachOriginalArtifact>
              <reduce>false</reduce>
              <reduceMergeABC>false</reduceMergeABC>
              <reduceMergeCF>false</reduceMergeCF>
              <reduceSortCPool>false</reduceSortCPool>
              <strip>false</strip>
              <sourceFile>myApp.mxml</sourceFile>
              <ignoreVersionIssues>true</ignoreVersionIssues>
              <skipTests>true</skipTests>
              <compilerWarnings>
                <warn-no-constructor>false</warn-no-constructor>
                <show-binding-warnings>false</show-binding-warnings>
                <warn-duplicate-variable-def>false</warn-duplicate-variable-def>
                <assignmentWithinConditional>true</assignmentWithinConditional>
                <constructorReturnsValue>true</constructorReturnsValue>
                <duplicateArgumentNames>true</duplicateArgumentNames>
                <duplicateVariableDef>true</duplicateVariableDef>
                <noConstructor>true</noConstructor>
              </compilerWarnings>
              <actionscriptFileEncoding>UTF-8</actionscriptFileEncoding>
              <licenses>
                <flexbuilder3>...</flexbuilder3>
              </licenses>
              <targetPlayer>10.2.0</targetPlayer>
              <accessible>true</accessible>
              <headlessServer>true</headlessServer>
              <localesCompiled>
                <locale>en_US</locale>
              </localesCompiled>
              <verboseStacktraces>true</verboseStacktraces>
              <generateHtmlWrapper>false</generateHtmlWrapper>
              <enableM2e>false</enableM2e>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
            <artifactId>license</artifactId>
            <version>3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexmojos-flex3-compatibility-layer</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-RC2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
            <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.4852</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
            <artifactId>adt</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.4852</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <sourceFile>ats.mxml</sourceFile>
          <ignoreVersionIssues>true</ignoreVersionIssues>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
          <compilerWarnings>
            <warn-no-constructor>false</warn-no-constructor>
            <show-binding-warnings>false</show-binding-warnings>
            <warn-duplicate-variable-def>false</warn-duplicate-variable-def>
            <assignmentWithinConditional>true</assignmentWithinConditional>
            <constructorReturnsValue>true</constructorReturnsValue>
            <duplicateArgumentNames>true</duplicateArgumentNames>
            <duplicateVariableDef>true</duplicateVariableDef>
            <noConstructor>true</noConstructor>
          </compilerWarnings>
          <actionscriptFileEncoding>UTF-8</actionscriptFileEncoding>
          <licenses>
            <flexbuilder3>...</flexbuilder3>
          </licenses>
          <targetPlayer>10.2.0</targetPlayer>
          <accessible>true</accessible>
          <headlessServer>true</headlessServer>
          <localesCompiled>
            <locale>en_US</locale>
          </localesCompiled>
          <verboseStacktraces>true</verboseStacktraces>
          <generateHtmlWrapper>false</generateHtmlWrapper>
          <enableM2e>false</enableM2e>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I found using MonsterDebugger that in runtime Menu object's and it's MenuItemRenderers are created.

I'm using Flex SDK 3.3, FlashBuilder 4, Maven 3.0.5, flexmojos-maven-plugin 4.0-RC2. Do you know what is the difference between building my application by FlashBuilder and Maven? Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Have you used `link-report` to examine the differences between your two builds?

Comment: And you are using a really really old version of flexmojos. The most recent one for Adobe Flex is curretnly 6.0.1 (But with a changed group-id: net.flexmojos.oss) and for Apache Flex it's 7.0.1

Comment: You are using an insanely old version of Flex and Flexmojos and you are duplicating quite a lot of configuration, as you should only need to configure the plugin in the pluginManagement or the plugin section (You currently have everything twice). What I would recommend is to have a look at the "modulename-config.xml" created in the target directory by FlexMojos (in 6.x and 7.x it's created automatically) and the "-dump-config" commandline option for FlashBuilder. If you compare the configuration dumps created you should find out what's going wrong quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

Purely building your project by means of flash builder won't offer you the agile development which comes with building your projects using a FlashBuilder/Maven integration. As a standalone development environment, flash builder tends to lack in the version and dependency management arena. As you see your project get grow and reach new releases, that is where you'll find using Maven with flash builder worthwhile compared to using the Apache Ant task-runner. Anything that can help manage cleanly manage dependencies, support modular and easily managed updates is definitely worthwhile. If you haven't already, you might want to checkout the adobe resource on flex/maven.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-maven-flexmojos-pt1.html